# Run Excel Macros on blocks of data

Tags: excel, vba

A dataset of around 60,000 rows is to be split into 200 almost equally sized files. Running this normally takes around 4 hours, while running the same Macro on an initial dataset of 20,000 rows takes around half an hour. So I am planning to run the Macro on 'blocks' of data of approximately 20,000 rows each (the actual splitting will be on the basis of the number of individual files, whose names are the entries of a column in the initial file), and I am wondering whether there is a simple way to 'wrap' the original macro in the new block-wise Macro. In the following schematic code:

- N = Number of rows in the whole dataset,
- M = Total number of files after splitting,
- i = each 'block' of performing the wrapper Macro (up to a maximum number of three),
- n = each row in the initial dataset,
- m = the number label of each file after the splitting (which is isomorphic to the name of the split file).

Schematically:

```
For i = 1 to 3, Start new block-wise Macro
     Start Original Macro with the original aim of splitting (N) rows into (M) files
     .....
     End Original Macro when m=M/3 (instead of when m=M)
End of a particular block corresponding to the application of the wrapper Macro
```

This is the original Macro (note that the schematic variable names above are different to what is in the actual Macro):

```
Public Sub SplitToFiles() 
   
    ' MACRO SplitToFiles
    ' Last update: 2019-05-28
    ' Author: mtone
    ' Version 1.2
    ' Description:
    ' Loops through a specified column, and split each distinct values into a separate file by making a copy and deleting rows below and above
    '
    ' Note: Values in the column should be unique or sorted.
    '
    ' The following cells are ignored when delimiting sections:
    ' - blank cells, or containing spaces only
    ' - same value repeated
    ' - cells containing "total"
    '
    ' Files are saved in a "Split" subfolder from the location of the source workbook, and named after the section name.
    
    Dim osh As Worksheet                         ' Original sheet
    Dim iRow As Long                             ' Cursors
    Dim iCol As Long
    Dim iFirstRow As Long                        ' Constant
    Dim iTotalRows As Long                       ' Constant
    Dim iStartRow As Long                        ' Section delimiters
    Dim iStopRow As Long
    Dim sSectionName As String                   ' Section name (and filename)
    Dim rCell As Range                           ' current cell
    Dim owb As Workbook                          ' Original workbook
    Dim sFilePath As String                      ' Constant
    Dim iCount As Integer                        ' # of documents created
    
    iCol = Application.InputBox("Enter the column number used for splitting", "Select column", 2, , , , , 1)
    iRow = Application.InputBox("Enter the starting row number (to skip header)", "Select row", 2, , , , , 1)
    iFirstRow = iRow
    
    Set osh = Application.ActiveSheet
    Set owb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    iTotalRows = osh.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    sFilePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    
    If Dir(sFilePath + "\Split", vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir sFilePath + "\Split"
    End If
    
    'Turn Off Screen Updating  Events
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Do
        ' Get cell at cursor
        Set rCell = osh.Cells(iRow, iCol)
        sCell = Replace(rCell.Text, " ", "")
    
        If sCell = "" Or (rCell.Text = sSectionName And iStartRow <> 0) Or InStr(1, rCell.Text, "total", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
            ' Skip condition met
        Else
            ' Found new section
            If iStartRow = 0 Then
                ' StartRow delimiter not set, meaning beginning a new section
                sSectionName = rCell.Text
                iStartRow = iRow
            Else
                ' StartRow delimiter set, meaning we reached the end of a section
                iStopRow = iRow - 1
    
                ' Pass variables to a separate sub to create and save the new worksheet. fileFormat = 51 corresponds to .xlsx extension
                CopySheet osh, iFirstRow, iStartRow, iStopRow, iTotalRows, sFilePath, sSectionName, 51
                iCount = iCount + 1
    
                ' Reset section delimiters
                iStartRow = 0
                iStopRow = 0
    
                ' Ready to continue loop
                iRow = iRow - 1
            End If
        End If
    
        ' Continue until last row is reached
        If iRow < iTotalRows Then
            iRow = iRow + 1
        Else
            ' Finished. Save the last section. fileFormat = 51 corresponds to .xlsx extension
            iStopRow = iRow
            CopySheet osh, iFirstRow, iStartRow, iStopRow, iTotalRows, sFilePath, sSectionName, 51
            iCount = iCount + 1
    
            ' Exit
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    
    'Turn On Screen Updating  Events
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    MsgBox Str(iCount) + " documents saved in " + sFilePath
        
End Sub

Public Sub DeleteRows(targetSheet As Worksheet, RowFrom As Long, RowTo As Long)
    
    Dim rngRange As Range
    Set rngRange = Range(targetSheet.Cells(RowFrom, 1), targetSheet.Cells(RowTo, 1)).EntireRow
    rngRange.Select
    rngRange.Delete
    
End Sub

Public Sub CopySheet(osh As Worksheet, iFirstRow As Long, iStartRow As Long, iStopRow As Long, iTotalRows As Long, sFilePath As String, sSectionName As String, fileFormat As XlFileFormat)
    Dim ash As Worksheet                         ' Copied sheet
    Dim awb As Workbook                          ' New workbook
    
    ' Copy bookXlFileFormat
    osh.Copy
    Set ash = Application.ActiveSheet
    
    ' Delete Rows after section
    If iTotalRows > iStopRow Then
        DeleteRows ash, iStopRow + 1, iTotalRows
    End If
    
    ' Delete Rows before section
    If iStartRow > iFirstRow Then
        DeleteRows ash, iFirstRow, iStartRow - 1
    End If
    
    ' Select left-topmost cell
    ash.Cells(1, 1).Select
    
    ' Clean up a few characters to prevent invalid filename
    sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, "/", " ")
    sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, "\", " ")
    sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, ":", " ")
    sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, "=", " ")
    sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, "*", " ")
    sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, ".", " ")
    sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, "?", " ")
    sSectionName = Strings.Trim(sSectionName)
    
    ' Save in same format as original workbook
    '
    ash.SaveAs sFilePath + "\Split\" + sSectionName, fileFormat
    
    ' Close
    Set awb = ash.Parent
    awb.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: It should be helpful edit your question to also show us the code you use. Do you copy the range or use arrays? Do you need the format of the copied range to be kept?

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: That's more like it.

Comment: As I understand it, your problem is more about finding a way to speed up the process than actually write a master Sub for blocks of ~20k rows. Am I correct ?

Answer (score 0):

To make your procedure work in chunks you need to make `SplitToFiles` more generic by taking parameters:

```
Public Sub SplitToFiles(ByVal StartRow As Long, ByVal EndRow As Long, ByVal SplitByColumn As Long)
    ' declare variables …

    iCol = SplitByColumn
    iRow = StartRow
```

Then make sure you take `StartRow` as the row to start with and make your loop exit, if the row `StartRow + AmountOfRows` is reached:

```
Do While iRow <= EndRow
```

Then you can wrap this into another procedure:

```
Public Sub SplitBlocksOfFiles()
    Const MAX_BLOCKS As Long = 3  ' Define the maximum of blocks to perform

    Dim SplitByColumn As Variant
    SplitByColumn = Application.InputBox("Enter the column number used for splitting", "Select column", 2, , , , , 1)
    If VarType(SplitByColumn) = vbBoolean And SplitByColumn = False Then Exit Sub  ' User pressed cancel

    Dim HeaderRows As Variant
    HeaderRows = Application.InputBox("How many header rows do we have?)", "Select row", 2, , , , , 1)
    If VarType(HeaderRows) = vbBoolean And HeaderRows = False Then Exit Sub  ' User pressed cancel

    Do
        Dim Block As Variant
        Block = Application.InputBox("Which of the " & MAX_BLOCKS  & " blocks do you want to perform now?)", "Select row", 2, , , , , 1)
        If VarType(Block) = vbBoolean And Block = False Then Exit Sub  ' User pressed cancel
    Loop While CLng(Block) > MAX_BLOCKS Or CLng(Block) < 1 ' If invalid number ask again
        

    Dim TotalAmountOfRows As Long
    TotalAmountOfRows =  ' ToDo: determine the amount of rows
    
    ' calculate start and end row for the block
    Dim StartRow As Long
    Dim EndRow As Long
   
    If Block = 1 Then  ' first block
        StartRow = HeaderRows + 1
        EndRow = StartRow + AmountOfRows - HeaderRows - 1
    ElseIf Block = MAX_BLOCKS Then  ' last block
        StartRow = AmountOfRows * (Block - 1) + 1
        EndRow = TotalAmountOfRows
    Else  ' all other blocks
        StartRow = AmountOfRows * (Block - 1) + 1
        EndRow = StartRow + AmountOfRows - 1
    End If

    ' run the splitting for the block only
    SplitToFiles StartRow, EndRow, CLng(SplitByColumn)
End Sub
```

So for `TotalAmountOfRows = 60002` total rows and `HeaderRows = 1` this will process the following blocks/rows

| Block | StartRow | EndRow |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 20000 |
| 2 | 20001 | 40000 |
| 3 | 40001 | 60002 |